# rename multiple attributes with simpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

```
<root>
  <gallery name="First"/>
  <gallery name="Second"/>
  <gallery name="Third"/>
</root>
```

I'm trying to rename multiple "name" attributes at once:

```
$rename = array();
foreach($_POST['name'] as $value) {
    $rename[] = $value;
}

$objXML = new SimpleXMLElement(XML_FILE_NAME, null, true);
$gallery = $objXML->xpath('/root/gallery/@name');
print_r($gallery);
print_r($rename);

$objXML->asXML(XML_FILE_NAME);
```

Returns:

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => First ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => Second ) ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => Third ) ) )

Array ( [0] => First New [1] => Second New [2] => Third New )
```

How can I get php to save the New values back to the XML? Does it need another foreach loop? The code seems to be getting too complex already.

I'm trying this, but no dice:

```
foreach( $objXML->xpath('/root/gallery/@name') as $gallery ) {
    $gallery = $_POST['name'];
}
```

Comment: i don't see how `$rename` was of any use in the code

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can use a variable by reference (so it actually modifies it) in a foreach loop.  For your code, it would be: `foreach( $objXML->xpath('/root/gallery/@name') as &$gallery ) {`.  Any changes made to `$gallery` will "stick".

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I already have in my example above. It's the bit inside the loop that I need to sort out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplexml is buid to returns node only. That's weird, but `'/root/gallery/@name'` and `'/root/gallery'`.

These two queries

```
$aList = $objXML->xpath('/root/gallery/@name');
$bList = $objXML->xpath('/root/gallery');
```

will return the same instances

```
for($i=0, $count=count($aList); $i<$count; $i++) {
  $a = $aList[$i];
  $b = $aList[$i];
  var_dump($a==$b); // true
}
```

So the only way for changing the attribute of a node is with the array syntaxe

```
foreach($aList as $node) {
  $node['name'] = 'foo' . $i;
}
var_dump($objXML);
```